# Docker bullseye image and udevadm command failing

Tags: linux, docker, udev, bullseye

I am trying to build a custom docker image using the image `python:3.7-slim-bullseye`.

Inside this image I run the command:

`RUN udevadm control --reload-rules || echo "done"`
which produces the error: `Failed to send reload request: No such file or directory`.

Moreover, when I run the command `RUN udevadm trigger` I get the error: `Failed to write 'change' to '/sys/devices/armv7_cortex_a7/uevent': Read-only file system`.

Any idea what is going on and what I could do to solve intent solving it?

Sincerely

Comment: Same here on balenalib/raspberrypi4-64-node:18.12. Worked fine earlier (on buster it was, I think?)